# How to return the response of Post request from a function in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, post

I have a function in my project that processes most of my API requests (see simplified draft below)

```
function sendRequest(){

    var reqbody;
    var resp;

    reqbody = unimportantRandomFunction();

    request.post({
        headers: {  'content-type'  : 'application/xml',
                    'accept'        : 'application/xml'},
        url: process.env.APIURL,
        body: reqbody
    }, function(error, response, body){
        resp = convert.xml2js(body, {compact:true});
    });

    return resp;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that request.post is asynchronous and by the time I get the response, an undifined value has already been returned.
I tried experimenting with promises (something I am entirely new to) but obviously I can't  place my return in a .then block either because that return will not belong to the sendRequest function (correct me if I'm wrong).
Any ideas where I could put my return statement to make it work, that is wait for the value of "resp" to be assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

Promise is used `sendRequest()`. And the response value is retrieved in the async function. At the following modified script, at first `sample()` is run. And `sendRequest()` is run, then the response value is retrieved at `console.log(res)`.

#### Modified script:

```
function sendRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reqbody;
    var resp;

    reqbody = unimportantRandomFunction();

    request.post(
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/xml",
          accept: "application/xml"
        },
        url: process.env.APIURL,
        body: reqbody
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) reject(error);
        resp = convert.xml2js(body, { compact: true });
        resolve(resp);
      }
    );
  });
}

async function sample() {
  const res = await sendRequest().catch(err => console.log(err));
  console.log(res);
}

sample();  // This function is run.
```

#### References:

- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Something I would add.  Depending on what they are using for a request lib, they very likely could just `return request.post`

Comment: @MindlessRouse Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `return request.post` which is the additional request. When you want to retrieve `error, response, body` of `function(error, response, body){` at `res` in `sample()`, how about modifying `resolve(resp);` to `resolve({ error: error, response: response, body: body });`? By this, you can retrieve each values at `res` of `const res = await sendRequest()`. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, it took me some time to understand how your solution aplies to my code, but it's finally working. Thanks for taking your time to help, you're awesome! ;)

Comment: @Tamás Kovács Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.